# uploading file and show its progress bar in cli using thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, file-upload, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I wrote a simple `python3` script for uploading files that runs in `CLI`. I using `requests.post(somewebservice.com)` for uploading files to server, but i want to add a progress bar to my script for tracking the progress of uploading. How I can find out state(percentage) of upload for use it in my progress bar?

If i know how to get that percentage or something like that, I can do threading things for parallel uploading and showing progress bar in `CLI` by myself.

Simple file uploading

```
payload = {'file': open(os.path.join(root, file), 'rb')}
response = requests.post("http://some-web.service.com:8000/upload",
                                             files=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tqdm` package: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(requests.ReadTimeout)):
    pass
```